Variable in Get Records Element not locating field value in Flow
I'm creating a flow to auto generate a ProjectID value on Opportunities once they hit a specific Stage. The ProjectID value should incrementally increase based off the largest value already present on any existing Opportunities for the Account. My variable in the Get Records Element is being set to a null value and I'm not sure why as in my scenario I already have an Opportunity which contains a ProjectID value of 'JEN0001'. I'm expecting my Get Records Element to store this value as the variable so I can update the value later in the flow.





try taking the opportunity where your Project_Id__c is populated, with some value example 'JEN001'. Then in your flow getRecord element clear all the condition and put Id = (id of the opportunity with JEN001 populated) as your only condition. Just hardcode the Id in here first and debug the flow, by right your varprojectId should hold this value now.

Yes the varprojectid variable located and stored the value 'JEN0001' when I hardcoded the Opp id in.

Removed the empty string logic from the Get Records element and the variable is now being passed.
